# How should I pass the value of price slider to the controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Here is my code,

```
var $range = $("#price-slider");
$range.ionRangeSlider({
    min: 130,
    max: 575,
    type: 'double',
    prefix: "$",
    prettify: false,
    hasGrid: true,
    onChange : function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Here, it would like to pass the value to the controller.
How should I use Ajax inside the `onChange` function

And my Ajax is something like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'hotelresults',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    from: from_val,
    to: to_val
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('.hotel_list').html(data);
  }
});
```

And also here,I dont know how to get the from and to value of price slider..

Someone help me..

Regards
Suganya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you soo much..Who were reply me,

It had tried like this way

```
onChange : function (data) {
        var from_num = data.fromNumber;
        var to_num =data.toNumber;
        $.ajax({
                // alert('hai');
                url: 'hotelresults',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 
                        from: from_num,
                        to: to_num, 
                },
                success: function(data){
                        $('.hotel_list').html(data);
                }
            });
}
```

And It works for me :) :D

Answer (score 2):

For ion range sliders , onChange function takes a parameter say data, which hold range values of slider.

In your case you can use **data.from** and **data.to** for range values inside ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'hotelresults',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    from: data.from,
    to: data.to
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('.hotel_list').html(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**SCRIPT**

```
var $range = $("#price-slider");
$range.ionRangeSlider({
    min: 130,
    max: 575,
    type: 'double',
    prefix: "$",
    prettify: false,
    hasGrid: true,
    onChange : function (data) {
        console.log(data.from)
        console.log(data.to)
    }
});
```

You can pass the value to AJAX by getting values like

`data.to` and `data.from`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/xaaw56bk/46/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax request inside the onchange() function and pass slider response into ajax.

**Example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $range = $("#price-slider").val();
$range.ionRangeSlider({
  min: 130,
  max: 575,
  type: 'double',
  prefix: "$",
  prettify: false,
  hasGrid: true,
  onChange : function (data) {
      //console.log(data);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'hotelresults',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "slider_response="+data,
        success: function(response) {
          $('.hotel_list').html(response);
        }
      });
  }
});
</script>
```

For getting value of slider you need to use `$("#price-slider").val()` instead of `$("#price-slider")`